# Setting up Sendgrid using AWS

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, firebase, sendgrid

I currently have a site where the data is hosted on Firebase and the static files are hosted on AWS (I registered my domain using NameCheap, but am routing to AWS using Route 53 and S3).

I now want to use SendGrid to send emails, but they are saying that I need to set up an SMTP server. I can't find anywhere what the best way to do this is. Can I get suggestions please on the best solution? I want to use SendGrid to send transactional email such as "Welcome to the site!", "Forgot Password", etc.

Answer (score 6):

There seems to be some misunderstanding here. You don't need to setup an SMTP server (that's the whole point of using a provider like SendGrid or SES). However, firebase is all client-side code, so if you want to do things like send emails or integrate third party APIs or do heavy computation that is not feasible on the client side, you'll have to have some server-side code running somewhere to manage those things.

You can read more about this in the [Firebase FAQ](https://www.firebase.com/docs/faq.html)

**Update** You can now achieve this using Firebase's integration with Zapier: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-11-25-fireabase-to-apis-with-zapier.html

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want to specifically use sendgrid? If you are already running on aws, you could use AWS SES instead. I've had nothing but problems getting sendgrid to work and finally gave up; with SES you can be up and running in minutes.

http://aws.amazon.com/ses/

Comment: I had just heard that SendGrid was better with analytics. But if it's much easier to use SES, then I'll try that.